# Rails Searchkick / Elasticsearch has_many and belongs_to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

Im trying to use Searchkick to run a search and return based on multiple models.

My book model contains this

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  searchkick

  has_many :book_subjects
  has_many :subjects, through: :book_subjects

  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :publisher

end
```

and then my controller has this

```
def index

 if params[:search].present?
   @books = Book.search(params[:search], operator: "or")
 else
  @books = Book.all
 end
end
```

I want the search results to search the associated models and return any results there too -- so the boo subject name, the author and the publisher.

thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your Book model you need to have a `search_data` block for the indexing.

```
def search_data
  attributes.merge(
    author_name: author(&:name)
    publisher_name: publisher(&:name)
    subjects_name: subjects.map(&:name)
  )
end
```

this will add the associations to your index.

You use the `.map` method for the `has_many` associations.

Comment: Thanks, this was a good point in the right direction. the subject_name didn't work, but figured it out.

Comment: does this update search_data when for example subject was edited?

Comment: there is a little error with `subject_name`. Correct way to do this with a has_many association: `subject_name: subjects.map(&:name)`

Comment: @railsey What worked for you re: `subject_name`? Because neither of the suggestions here work for me.