# Rails 4 searchkick with many-to-many relationsip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, searchkick

How to implement a Category filter for searchkick. Basically I have an input field that takes the query term, but I also want a dropdown that users can pick a category to search from or search in ALL categories. There is a many-to-many relationship between posts and categories

My models are:

```
-- post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :post_categories
 has_many :categories, through: :post_categories
 searchkick text_start: [:title]
end

-- category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :post_categories
    has_many :posts, through: :post_categories
end

--post_category.rb
class PostCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :category
end
```

Now in my posts_controller index action, I have the following, which works so far by returning all posts that match the query parameter, or returns all posts if no query parameter is provided in the search input.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        query = params[:q].presence || "*"
        @posts = Post.search (query)
    end
end
```

This works well so far. But I also want to add a category filter in the view, so that the user can choose to search  for the query string within a particular category, or search in all categories if no category is selected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding a category filter yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per searchkick documentation, you can add parameters to .search query - see [here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) section Queries, specifically where. Sample from docs:

```
Product.search "apples", where: {in_stock: true}, limit: 10, offset: 50
```

Should be smt like

```
Post.search query, where: {category: [some_array]}
```

Note - searchkick gem converts conditions from where statement to ElasticSearch filters (see [here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/668b7948df1d84548690633968de0174c539fc9b/lib/searchkick/query.rb#L669))

**Update** - for searching by attributes of related objects (not model itself), you should include its fields into search_index - see sample [here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/74)

Add the category titles to the search_data method.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  def search_data
    attributes.merge(
      categories_title: categories.map(&:title)
    )
  end
end
```

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046428/rails-searchkick-elasticsearch-has-many-and-belongs-to-associations) question on related topic

By default search_data of searchkick is return of serializable_hash model call -see [sources](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/a31489fd1ac4ecb228440f9e895294f523a47f86/lib/searchkick/model.rb#L95) for reference.

```
def search_data
  respond_to?(:to_hash) ? to_hash : serializable_hash
end unless method_defined?(:search_data)
```

Which does not include anything of associations by default, unless passed with :include parameter - [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5b368010f64106f7b87a4306b41adcefa856ab67/activemodel/lib/active_model/serialization.rb#L97)

```
 def serializable_hash(options = nil)
    ...
    serializable_add_includes(options) do ..
 end

 def serializable_add_includes(options = {}) #:nodoc:
   return unless includes = options[:include]
 ...
 end
```

Comment: Yep I tried that method already but doesn't yield anything. I tried `@posts = Post.search (query), where: {category: ["Wedding"]}` but still returns no results. not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Just in case, check for evident syntax error - call `Post.search(query, where: {..})` - everything inside ( )

Comment: On a general rule, avoid putting space between method name and bracket - write call(params) and not call (params) - you can easily search for this, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675093/spacing-around-parentheses-in-ruby)

Comment: see update - associations are not indexed by default

Comment: Yes, setting the search_data for the associated models worked. Thank you very much Pavel.